# error 404 both on github pages and netlify

Tags: rstudio, github-pages, quarto, netlify-cli

[image: the image shows the error when i try to deploy my site via netlify, the same error is shown when in try to deploy via github pages]

[image: Here are the files i have created using quarto in r studio]
Just build a data science portfolio via quarto in rstudio however i try to deploy the portfolio on git hub pages and am getting an error 404, similarly on netlify.

Comment: Here is a link of the deployed app: https://scintillating-pastelito-d37e10.netlify.app/

Comment: On Github, change your repository name to `kalyanjr.github.io`. Try re-deploying. If it still does not work, check that you followed all steps from this [tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site)

Comment: Your repo doesn’t have any html files. Open up any of your qmd files then click “Render” in rstudio. It should generate html files from your quarto doc.

Comment: You might want to review https://quarto.org/docs/publishing/